Grad-Cam heat map with Swin Transformer doesn't work
I used the swin-transformer model of pytorch.
model = models.swin_b(weights='IMAGENET1K_V1')


model structure is

SwinTransformer(
  (features): Sequential(
    (0): Sequential(
      (0): Conv2d(3, 128, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(4, 4))
      (1): Permute()
      (2): LayerNorm((128,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
    )
    (1): Sequential(
      (0): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((128,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=384, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=128, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.0, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((128,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=128, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (1): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((128,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=384, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=128, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.021739130434782608, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((128,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=128, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
    )
    (2): PatchMerging(
      (reduction): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=256, bias=False)
      (norm): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
    )
    (3): Sequential(
      (0): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((256,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=256, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.043478260869565216, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((256,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=1024, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=256, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (1): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((256,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=768, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=256, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.06521739130434782, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((256,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=256, out_features=1024, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=256, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
    )
    (4): PatchMerging(
      (reduction): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=512, bias=False)
      (norm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
    )
    (5): Sequential(
      (0): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.08695652173913043, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (1): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.10869565217391304, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (2): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.13043478260869565, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (3): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.15217391304347827, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (4): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.17391304347826086, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (5): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.1956521739130435, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (6): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.21739130434782608, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (7): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.2391304347826087, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (8): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.2608695652173913, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (9): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.2826086956521739, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (10): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.30434782608695654, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (11): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.32608695652173914, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (12): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.34782608695652173, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (13): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.3695652173913043, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (14): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.391304347826087, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (15): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.41304347826086957, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (16): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.43478260869565216, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (17): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=1536, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=512, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.45652173913043476, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((512,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=2048, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=512, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
    )
    (6): PatchMerging(
      (reduction): Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=1024, bias=False)
      (norm): LayerNorm((2048,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
    )
    (7): Sequential(
      (0): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.4782608695652174, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
      (1): SwinTransformerBlock(
        (norm1): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (attn): ShiftedWindowAttention(
          (qkv): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=3072, bias=True)
          (proj): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.5, mode=row)
        (norm2): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
        (mlp): MLP(
          (0): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=4096, bias=True)
          (1): GELU(approximate='none')
          (2): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
          (3): Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=1024, bias=True)
          (4): Dropout(p=0.0, inplace=False)
        )
      )
    )
  )
  (norm): LayerNorm((1024,), eps=1e-05, elementwise_affine=True)
  (permute): Permute()
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
  (flatten): Flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
  (head): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=2, bias=True)
)


Also, I set up the target layer like this

    targets = None
    target_layers = [model.features[-1][-1].norm1]

and the grad-cam code is here
    n = 0
    for i in rln_image_list:
        grayscale_cams = None

    # Read sample image and transform into tensor
        img = np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(rln_dir, i)))
        img = np.float32(img) / 255
        input_tensor = preprocess_image(img, mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
        input_tensor = input_tensor.to(device)

    # Calculate highlight level
        with GradCAM(model=model, target_layers=target_layers) as cam:
            grayscale_cams = cam(input_tensor=input_tensor, targets=targets)
            cam_image = show_cam_on_image(img, grayscale_cams[0,:], use_rgb=True)
    
    # Visualize
        cam = np.uint8(255*grayscale_cams[0,:])
        cam = cv2.merge([cam, cam, cam])
        images = np.hstack((np.uint8(255*img), cam_image))
        result = Image.fromarray(images)
        result.save(os.path.join(cat1_dir, "Swin_b_" + i)) 
        print('#'+str(n), "Saved:", "Swin_b_" + i)
        n += 1 here


the heat map of result was not shown.

there were some lines as heat map results
I really don't know what problem is. I can't the target layer of swintransformer model.
I just tried to several target layers, those were same results (vertical line)
please advise me.
Thank you
